# NumPy implementation slower than the for-loop version

Tags: python, numpy

I have two functions, `np_prod` and `slice_prod`, that perform the same element-wise operations on two NumPy arrays, `mat1` and `mat2`, which have the same shape. However, I noticed that the `np_prod` function is slower than the `slice_prod` function. I used the following code to measure the performance:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

shape = (10, 600, 600)
mat1 = np.random.rand(*shape).astype(np.float32)
mat2 = np.random.rand(*shape).astype(np.float32)

def np_prod(mat1, mat2):
    res = mat1.copy()
    res *= -1
    res += 1
    res *= (1 - mat2)
    res *= -1
    res += 1
    return res

def slice_prod(mat1, mat2):
    res = mat1.copy()
    for i in range(res.shape[0]):
        res[i] *= -1
        res[i] += 1
        res[i] *= (1 - mat2[i])
        res[i] *= -1
        res[i] += 1
    return res

N = 400
print("For loop product: ", timeit.timeit("slice_prod(mat1, mat2)", setup="from __main__ import slice_prod, mat1, mat2", number=N))
print("Numpy product: ", timeit.timeit("np_prod(mat1, mat2)", setup="from __main__ import np_prod, mat1, mat2", number=N))
```

The obtained result is

```
For loop product:  15.605191999999999
Numpy product:  18.899588700000002
```

My NumPy version is 1.24.2. I expected the NumPy implementation to be faster due to its optimized array operations, but it seems like the for-loop version is faster in this case. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can optimize `np_prod` to be faster?

(The example I provided is a simplified version of my use case. In my own code the performance diffrence is more notable, like 2x, measured using time.perf_counter)

Comment: "how I can optimize np_prod to be faster?" -Looks like you already did. And called it slice_prod :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of cache usage: The original code handles 14MB of data, whereas the second version handles 10 blocks of 1.4MB each.

On my computer for example, the CPU's L3 cache is 8 MB. So for the first version, the data being worked on can't fit in the cache and has to be read from memory on each operation. In the second version, after reading each block to the cache, all the operations can act on the data in the cache.

Changing the code so that the blocks being worked on can fit in the L2 or L1 caches should yield even better performance.

Comment: Indeed, a smaller shape will result in the NumPy variant being faster.

Comment: @9769953 With `shape = (10, 200, 200)` difference is even more noticeable

Comment: @Ohibò What times do you get for that?

Comment: @KellyBundy with `10 000` loops and a shape of `(10, 200, 200)` I get `18.93` for `slice_prod` and `31.93` for `np_prod`. Maybe because now it fit in L2 cache too? Numpy does not deal automatically with such optimizations?

Comment: @Ohibò On my M1 system, `(10, 200, 200)` is slightly faster with NumPy, while `(10, 100, 100)` is notably faster. It's similar on an older Intel x86_64 chip. Not sure what's up with your system that a smaller shape slows NumPy down relatively even more.

Comment: @Ohibò I see you edited. Originally you said `shape = (10, 200, 20)`. What times with that?

Comment: `numpy` code is in the middle, between python where you wrote the iterative batch processing, and the low level compiler and processor dependent cache handling.